# Is this graph transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, logic, proof-writing

I have a graph $G = (A,B)$ which is transitive when: $(a,b) ∈ B ∧ (b,c) ∈ B → (a,c) ∈ B$.

**How can I prove that $G$ is transitive iff it's acyclic?**

Comment: I think you're missing a $B$ there. Also  did you mean "iff" instead of "off"? In which case it's not true. The complete graphs are transitive but very cyclic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prove this: it is false.

Let $G$ be transitive and nonempty.  Then every connected component is a complete graph.

Let $x$ and $y$ be in the same component, and let $x P y$ be the shortest path.  If $P$ has $n \ge 2$ edges, then write $P = x v_2 v_3 \dots y$ (note that it is possible for $v_3 = y$).  Then $x v_3 \in E$, so $x v_3 \dots y$ is a shorter path, a contradiction.  So all shortest paths in the same component have $1$ edge, and all connected vertices are adjacent.